# error C2039: 'Open' : is not a member of 'std::basic_fstream

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, compiler-errors

When i call

```
void fileOpen(const char*
 fname_){file_.Open(fname_,ios::in|ios::out|ios::ate|ios::binary);};
```

Function like 
tempobj->fileOpen("LastID.dat");

It gives me the error

```
Error   23  error C2039: 'Open' : is not a member of 'std::basic_fstream<_Elem,_Traits>'
```

How do i resolve this. This is the class I have this function. It is template class

```
#ifndef FileHandlerh_h
#define FileHandlerh_h
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
template <class T>
class FileHandler
{
    private:
        fstream file_;


    public:
        FileHandler(){};

        FileHandler(const char* fname_){fileOpen(fname_);};

        void fileOpen(const char* fname_){file_.Open(fname_,ios::in|ios::out|ios::ate|ios::binary);};

        void fileWrite(T);
        void fileSeekWrite(T,int);
        T fileRead(int);
        int getNoOfRecords();

        ~FileHandler(){file_.close();};

};
```

Help me with this...!!

Comment: just read the error message `'Open' : is not a member of 'std::basic_fstream<_Elem,_Traits>'`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C++ is case sensitive. You need to use `open()` instead of `Open()`.

Comment: And 38 SO users time.  Close your question by marking it answered.

Answer (score 3):

Use a lowercase `O`, perhaps? It's quite uncommon to see capitals in function names in the standard library.